Is there a way to add database and schema name dynamically in @query in spring boot repository level
I have multiple schemas and in application.properties file I have mentioned one schema name.
But I have a repository which has the query in which I am querying table in different schema. I am passing the db and schema name as a parameter to method.
@Query(value="select * from :db.:schema.Customer",nativeQuery=true)
List<Entity> fetchEntities(@param("db") String db, @Param("schema") String schema);

But this is not working. Any help is appreciated.

Not sure if this will work, but have you tried replacing :db with ?1 and :schema with ?2?

Using parameters for schema names is not supported due to the way JPA prepares the SQL queries under the hood. However, you can construct the SQL query string, set the schema dynamically, and utilize EntityManager to execute the query:
 @PersistenceContext
 private EntityManager entityManager;

 public List<Entity> fetchEntities(String db, String schema) {
      String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + db + "." + schema + ".Customer";
      Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql, Entity.class);
  }

